# Event handlers in Blender

Tags: game-engine

I have a scene in blender with objects placed at strategic locations.The main object in the scene is just one human character. I would want to be able to have events such as:

Human character walks past a box and a script sends a response such as sound.

How do I go about implementing that in blender

Comment: Would you like to use Python as language?

Comment: @soreigon Yes, I would

Comment: Have you surfed on the internet looking for answers?

Comment: @soreigon Yes, I have. I am a newbie to blender currently working with a team to get this done.

Comment: Can you give more details about what your event should do? : Human character walks past a box and a script sends a response such as sound.? I can't figure out what response you want to send.

Comment: @fiskerXO Exactly as you said. Something as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You setup event triggers using game engine logic bricks within the [Logic Editor window](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Screen_Layout)

There are [several sensors](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Sensors) available, collision and near would work. (Touch appears to have disappeared from recent versions) These sensors can then run python scripts or initiate other actions using available actuators.

A search on youtube for blender game engine tutorial will bring up several options to show you the basics of using the game engine.